# Кириллица и request Node.js

Tags: node.js, кириллица, request

Нужно получить слово от сайта http://sluchajnoe.ru/slovo.php

```
var req = require("request");
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

req("http://sluchajnoe.ru/slovo.php", function (error, res, body){
    var wordRandom = iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), "UTF-8");
    wordRandom = wordRandom.replace(/<font size="200%">(.+)/gi, function(match, p1){
        console.log(p1);
        return p1;
    });
});
```

Код выдаёт краказябру. Что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно изначально принимать данные как `Buffer`. Для этого требуется вызвать `request` с параметром `encoding: null`.

Сама страница отдаётся как `'text/html; charset=CP1251'`, соответственно и `decode` надо делать с `win1251`.

Так должно работать:

```
var req = require("request");
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

req(
    {
        url: "http://sluchajnoe.ru/slovo.php", 
        encoding: null
    }, 

    function (error, res, body){

    var wordRandom = iconv.decode(body, "win1251");
    wordRandom = wordRandom.replace(/<font size="200%">(.+)/gi, function(match, p1){
        console.log(p1);
        return p1;
    });
});
```